# AspNet.Identity role Management

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am using Asp.net 4.5.1 webForm application with EF codefirst. for Authentication I am using  Microsoft.AspNet.Identity. I want in the loging page after I check that user is correct also check user's role. if user is in admin role, send user to admin folder(page) or if user in users role send the user to users folder(page). how can I check user is in Admin role or not?

this is my Login code:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValid)
        {
            // Validate the user password
            var manager = new UserManager();
            ApplicationUser user = manager.Find(inputEmail.Text, inputPassword.Text);
            if (user != null)
            {
                IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, user, false);

                if (//user is in admin role)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("UserPage");
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("AdminPage");
                }


            }
            else
            {
                //Show error message that User is Incorrect
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `UserManager.IsInRole(User.Identity.GetUserId(), "RoleName")`

Moreover refer to : [Understand IsInRole with character case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20138596/2871663)

Tip: Try exploring any assembly in "Object Browser" (Ctrl+Alt+J) in Visual Studio.