# Automatically assign default role

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, roles

How is it possible the automatically assign a default role to a registered user. I'm trying this but it is not working and I'm getting the error:

```
[ProviderException: The role 'Member' was not found.]
```

This is what I do:

Seed my default role so it exists from the start:

```
// Configuration.cs, Seed method.

if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Member"))
{
    var store = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
    var manager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(store);
    var role = new IdentityRole { Name = "Member" };

    manager.Create(role); // Member role gets created in AspNetRoles table.
}
```

Than after update-database, I add a registered user to that role:

```
// AccountController, Register method (POST).

var user = new ApplicationUser { ... }

if (.. Succeeded)
{
    ..
    if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(user.UserName, "Member"))
        Roles.AddUserToRole(user.UserName, "Member");

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

When registering a new account, I get the error:

```
[ProviderException: The role 'Member' was not found.] // Member exits in AspNetRoles

Line 176:                    if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(user.UserName, "Member"))
Line 177:                         Roles.AddUserToRole(user.UserName, "Member");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong role manager. `Roles` is very likely the `Simple Membership` roles provider and not the one from `Identity`. Try the following:

```
if (.. Succeeded)
{
    ..
    // if (!await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user.Id, "Member"))
    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "Member");

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

I commented out the `IsInRoleAsync`-check as it is not needed IMO if you just created the user.

If not already done, you need to create an async action to use `async`/`await`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterModel model)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Is my seeding method also using the wrong role manager or can I leave it like that?

Comment: @user3231419: No, there you are using `RoleManager<IdentityRole>` which is the correct one, hence the role showing up in the `AspNetRoles` table and not some `webpages_Roles` table...

Comment: Found a little problem with using this method: After I register a new user, the user gets assigned to the "Member"-role in the database but not yet on the _Layout.cshtml page where I check if the active user is a member. It only recognizes that the user has the member-role when I logout and login again, any idea what went wrong?

Comment: @user3231419: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495249/mvc-5-addtorole-requires-logout-before-it-works