# Asp.Net Identity 2 Password reset link No of clicks

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

How can I know the user clicked the password link for the first time only in Asp.Net Identity 2 .
If user click the link multiple times it should not work.We can set the time for the link but how to set no clicks in the token generated.

Comment: just define flag and set value is true when user click on first time .

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i am looking that is there any possibility    that it can be included in the token generated without checking from Database.

Comment: How could it be?  If I hit back the page isn't going to be reloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store the number of clicks just use a flag in your database described by GujjuDeveloper

If you want to be sure that the link isn't used a second time you can invalidate the token used in the URL by calling 
    `userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync()`

For more information about revoking a token please read this post: [Revoke token generated by UserTokenProvider in ASP.NET Identity 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22755700/revoke-token-generated-by-usertokenprovider-in-asp-net-identity-2-0)

Comment: Then i think it's better to call `userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync()` after user reset the password.

Comment: I do it just before generation of a new token wich is then send via email to the user.