# ASP.Net Identity GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am working on a MVC project to separate identity stuff from the startup MVC project. On user registration when executes the line

```
UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userId)
```

it will throw System.ArgumentException with message

> If a list of purposes is specified, the list cannot contain null entries or entries that are comprised solely of whitespace characters.
>   Parameter name: purposes

Stack trace

```
at System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Protect(Byte[] userData, String[] purposes)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.DataProtection.MachineKeyDataProtector.Protect(Byte[] userData)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.AppBuilderExtensions.CallDataProtectionProvider.CallDataProtection.Protect(Byte[] userData)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.DataProtectorTokenProvider`2.<GenerateAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.<GenerateUserTokenAsync>d__fe.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Robot.ACG.Web.Controllers.AccountController.<Register>d__15.MoveNext() in...
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: are you sure error prompting on this line?

Comment: It throws on this line when on Debug.

Comment: What is `userId`? What type?

Comment: I create the user above this line and gets the created users id in to this.
in my case this is an int.

Comment: According to Microsoft, this method expects a `TKey` argument. Check out this thread, get a proper `user` object and pass its `id´ **property** instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22755700/revoke-token-generated-by-usertokenprovider-in-asp-net-identity-2-0

Comment: There is no problem with the user.Id. I've checked against the database.

Answer (score 1):

`GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync` generates a token. Problem might come from your different servers:

> If your token was generated on one server, and then attempting to validate it on another. Reason for that is that the token is protected via MachineKey.Protect. That is configured on OWIN initialisation.

From [Max Vasilyev, Trailmax Tech](http://tech.trailmax.info/2015/05/asp-net-identity-invalid-token-for-password-reset-or-email-confirmation/).

Comment: In my case I have both projects in same solution. So I hope the machine key will be the same.
I tried with machinekey in web.config also. Still the same.

Comment: Its all about token. If you call ConfirmEmailAsync then the token is passed to VerifyUserTokenAsync(userId, "Confirmation", token) where “Confirmation” is a purpose.

Comment: @AsiriDissa: Machine key has nothing to do with the solution. Machine keys, by default, are generated per site in IIS. If you need to share the machine key between sites, you need to generate one in IIS and then apply it in the Web.config of each site manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you should not pass an Id, but a user, at least when you are using asp.net Core:

```
UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user)
```