# In which actions is the security stamp needed?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, identity

As described in [What is ASP.NET Identity's IUserSecurityStampStore interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487322/what-is-asp-net-identitys-iusersecuritystampstoretuser-interface) security stamp is changed on password change or when a login is removed. I guess the security stamp verification is made on login. I'm wondering whether there are any other actions on which this verification is needed. Also is the security stamp value used in some methods such as email confirmation token generation or password generation etc.

Comment: Well the answer to the linked question says it can be called on a specific interval so that's one thing.