# Handling password change in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization

Imagine the following scenarion.

1. User is authenticated and get an authentication cookie. Which means one shouldn't enter username and password once again.
   I store only username in authentication cookie.
2. A hacker steals user's authentication cookie somehow. Admin decides to change a password for a user but a hacker is still authenticated and can access the system!

As far as I can understand authentication cookie can't be decrypted anywhere but serverside, isn't it?

Is it safe to store a password or a password hash as a custom claim in authentication cookie so I can compare it later and remove authentication from discriminated users?
What's a best practice for it? Or am I doing or asking something completely wrong?

Comment: You can implement refresh tokens to add expiration to tokens. Even if a hacker gets it which you wouldn't know when then it will still expire.

Comment: Yes, that's a nice idea and I missed it but a bit complex since I need to store extra data while I already have a password which I can change. 
If a hacker ( theoretically ) can't decrypt a cookie than I can store a password there, why not? Or can he?

Comment: You can never assume that a hacker cannot decrypt  your data. `Refresh Token` exists for this sole purpose, so that user cannot abuse the access token for a long time.

Comment: How about this, let's say you implemented refresh tokens and your user logged in. He now gets a token for authentication. Somehow a hacker got hold of that token. User quickly changes password so if the change password is successful you can force expire the previous token and grant the user a new one. Hacker now has an obsolete token.

Comment: The hacker wouldn't care less on decrypting the token. He would just use it for authorization by adding it to the request header as is.

Comment: @norekhov It is never been a good idea to implement security ourselves. ASP.Net Identity team thinks through all the scenarios you stated. Please look at **ASP.Net Identity** so that you can get ideas even if you do not plan to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I can understand authentication cookie can't be decrypted
>   anywhere but serverside, isn't it?

Authentication Cookie is encrypted using Machine Key. It is hard to decrypt back without machine key, but it is not impossible.

> Is it safe to store a password or a password hash as a custom claim in
>   authentication cookie so I can compare it later and remove
>   authentication from discriminated users? What's a best practice for
>   it? Or am I doing or asking something completely wrong?

No, you do not want to store password inside claim. It won't solve the hacking problem, or even make it worst.

You can implement [security stamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487322/what-is-asp-net-identitys-iusersecuritystampstoretuser-interface) like ASP.Net Identity which basically logout user from everywhere.

Comment: Ok now I see. I used  "Authentification" lib. What I missed is "Identity" lib. In my case I think it's easier to implement it manually than to use Identity lib. Thanks!