# How to reset authorization token in asp.net after email changing?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, token

I have asp net web application. It use asp net identity 2. If i change my email, my webapi token stay valid. How i can reset token? Sorry for my bad language.

Ok, I issue a token as follows: 
1) User call webapi method (get request for **{{host}}/token**. Method find this user from usercontext (username,password) in user repositories. if user found, system generate token.

```
var tokenExpiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(1); 
var ticket = accountManager.generateTicket(user.UserName, tokenExpiration);
if (ticket != null){
var token = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
return new TokenResponse{
Token = token,
TokenExpires = tokenExpiration.TotalSeconds
};
}
```

Code for "generateTicket":

```
ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName));

            var props = new AuthenticationProperties()
            {
                IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(tokenExpiration),
            };

            return new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
```

Comment: post some code which shows what have you tried till now. You issue seems interesting

Comment: Unfortunately, until now i have not found methods for reset the token. The token is issued for the mobile application. It is issued for the authorization of a particular user, that he could use webapi. If user has change his email, toke stay valid. User can still use webapi. I thought that if you call method SignOut(), then not only the cookies but also the token are reset.

Comment: The solution will lie in how are you issuing and validating the token. That's y i asked you to post that code

Comment: i try add this code in ask question,

Comment: I'm try to delete claim (identity.DeleteClaim()), but this not work for me.

Comment: and how is it validated?

Comment: I don't know. I added [authorize] prefix before API methods.

Comment: I think, owin.oauth validate users.

Comment: I have issue in the same to you. Are you had answer?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to invalidate a token is to add claim with a value from user's DB record which will be changed after a certain event (like email change), then on a new request to the API, the token's claim value must be checked that match with user's current DB record. There is a thing called **SecurityStamp** which is part of Asp.Net identity which does just that. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487322/what-is-asp-net-identitys-iusersecuritystampstoretuser-interface).

To enable the automatic SecurityStamp claim in token issuing process you need to define your user **IUserSecurityStampStore**:

```
public class MyUserStore : IUserSecurityStampStore<ApplicationUser>
{
   // some code
}
```

there is an example [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/a-simple-implementation-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity).

In the end, you need to check on the right place the current token SecurityStamp claim with user's DB security stamp. Here is a sample of WebAPI authorization attribute:

```
    public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var user = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity;
            if (!user.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return false;
            }


            var principals = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            if (!authorizationValidator.SecurityStampMatch(GetClaimValue(principals, "AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp"), user.GetGuidUserId()))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        private string GetClaimValue(ClaimsIdentity principals, string claimType)
        {
            var claim = principals.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.Equals(claimType));
            return claim?.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Just to point for extra clearance the change email, confirm phone number, change password thigger Asp.Net Identity to regenerate the Security Stamp so you don't have to worry about that.

---

Edit:

the authorizationValidator has this code in SecurityStampMatch:

```
public bool SecurityStampMatch(string securityStampClaim, Guid userId)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(securityStampClaim))
    {
        return false;
    }

    var usersSecurityStamp = _userManager.GetSecurityStamp(userId);
    return securityStampClaim.Equals(usersSecurityStamp);
}
```