# Configuring IUserTokenProvider for a project using Identity Server 3 and AspNet Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver3

I'm having a hard time trying to understand the correct way to configure `IUserTokenProvider` for my `UserManager` in my identity server. My goal with this is to be able to reset a user's password.
First, I understand that I need to configure a provider such as:

```
var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("MyAppName");
```

but I'm not sure where I should put this code. Would it be on my `UserManager` constructor?

This is how my constructor looks like right now, but it doesn't seems to be right, otherwise, how would I change the purpose for the validation and creation?

```
public UserManager(UserStore store)
            : base(store)
        {

            var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("MyAppName");
            UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(provider.Create("EmailConfirmation"));
        }
```

And one last question, does this provider automatically handle situations where a token was successfully used before in order to protect against further malicious requests?

PS: I'm using EntityFramework behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this if it's a public property (this is how a lot of Identity examples handle it).

```
        var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("MyAppName");
        var userManager = new UserManager(userStore)
        {
            UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(provider.Create("EmailConfirmation"))
        };
```

And as for the last question, if you're using the EntityFramework (or any implementation that supports SecurityStamps for that matter), yes you are protected. [What is ASP.NET Identity's IUserSecurityStampStore<TUser> interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487322/what-is-asp-net-identitys-iusersecuritystampstoretuser-interface) is a good starting reference for understanding SecurityStamps.