# Microsoft AspNet Identity 2.0.0.0 - Columns purpose

Tags: asp.net-identity

I need some information about **purpose db tables**.

For example, in table **AspNetUsers** what is the purpose of the

**SecurityStamp** or **LockoutEndDateUtc** columns ? How can I use the columns ?

There is someone that can help me please ?

Thank in advance

Comment: If you want DB tables I assume you want to query it directly. Maybe you'll have access to `[DB name].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` or `[DB name].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. Using those two tables I would be able to see table and column names even of the tables I had no SELECT permission for. (given that is MSSQL DB)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i need some information about the puropose columns.

Comment: You'll see column value type, length in if it's nullable or not, etc. in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. Again, if it's MSSQL. Other DBs should have ways to query schema as well though.

Comment: I don't need this information (value type, length etc..) I need the column purpose !!!! In SecurityStamp  what information i find ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `SecurityStamp`:

> the primary purpose of the SecurityStamp is to enable sign out everywhere. The basic idea is that whenever something security related is changed on the user, like a password, it is a good idea to automatically invalidate any existing sign in cookies, so if your password/account was previously compromised, the attacker no longer has access.
>   [more details in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19505060/2091230)

`LockoutEndDateUtc`, set together with `LockoutEnabled`, will allow locking out the user. [more details in this blog post](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/06/asp-net-identity-user-lockout/).